# Trying to write a function generating M normally distributed samples of length N

Tags: python, random, normal-distribution

I'm trying to write a function (rangNM) generating M normally distributed samples of length N and for some reason this results in a syntax error at line 4. Does anyone know what might be causing this?
Thanks in advance for the help.

```
def rangNM(N, M):
    iseed == 0
    sample = []
    for iseed < M:
       np.random.seed(iseed)
       sample.append(np.random.normal(scale=1, loc=0, size=N))
       iseed += 1
    return(sample)

rangNM(10, 5)
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `while` instead of `for`? `while iseed < M:`

Comment: welcome to SO. Why do you have single quotes around the entire code syntax?

Answer (score 0):

You should either use a `for` loop or a `while` loop:

```py
# using for loop
def rangNM(N, M):
    sample = []
    for iseed in range(M):
       np.random.seed(iseed)
       sample.append(np.random.normal(scale=1, loc=0, size=N))
    return(sample)

# using while loop
def rangNM(N, M):
    iseed = 0
    sample = []
    while iseed < M:
       np.random.seed(iseed)
       sample.append(np.random.normal(scale=1, loc=0, size=N))
       iseed += 1
    return(sample)
```